# Can a Syrian citizen get a US visa after the current administration revoked the travel ban?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, us-visa, syrian-citizens

Has the travel ban been fully revoked formcitzens of Syria and others? Is it possible to apply for a Visitor visa if you are a syrian Citizen? I know the odds are slim when it comes to getting one but can one still apply?